# I need an illustration about merge sort algorithm ? (recursive invocation step by step please)

Tags: algorithm, sorting, recursion

I'm stuck with the recursion used in merge sort , I can't understand it , I tried to but I just can't understand how a computer would execute this algorithm .

for example how this algorithm would sort the selection <5,2,4,7,1,2,3,6> .

I know how the algorithm merges two lists , but I need to see the stack of recursive calls . I know a lot of questions were asked on this topic but I need to understand the recursive part of the algorithm. I am too confused.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XaqR3G_NVoo ;)

Comment: The video doesn't show the regrouping of elements after a merge. For example, once  two single people are merged, they become a now sorted group of  2. The order of operations seems correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Top down merge sort is left first, depth first. Using | to indicate splitting of array, using youtube video sequence

```
|4 2 8 6 0 5 1 7 3 9|
|4 2 8 6 0|5 1 7 3 9|
|4 2|8 6 0|
|4|2|
|2 4|
    |8|6 0|
      |6|0|
      |0 6|
    |0 6 8|
|0 2 4 6 8|
          |5 1|7 3 9|
          |5|1|
          |1 5|
              |7|3 9|
                |3|9|
                |3 9|
              |3 7 9|
          |1 3 5 7 9|
|0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9|
```

Compare to bottom up merge sort:

```
|4 2 8 6 0 5 1 7 3 9|
|4|2|8|6|0|5|1|7|3|9|
|2 4|6 8|0 5|1 7|3 9|
|2 4 6 8|0 1 5 7|3 9|
|0 1 2 4 5 6 7 8|3 9|
|0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9|
```